# What strategies should I follow while searching for open source projects

Tags: source-code

I am fan of reusing stuff where possible, ever try to start developing any piece of software I search at following websites to get related software before developing it from scratch,

- GitHub
- Sourceforge

Anyone know of any other useful resource that I can put in my search list for open source projects ?

To be specific I am after a open source project which is consuming SSRS but using a custom UI, as specified in this SO question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424925/ssrs-with-custom-web-ui

Have been searching for days, found projects that use Java or other languages but non that uses C# along with HTML etc.. consuming SSRS for reporting. I am after code to be exact.

Comment: Note that you can ask for recommendations of open source software on [softwarerecs.se]. But your question needs to be specific (i.e., describe your use case, list all requirements).

Comment: What I meant is that your question on SR would likely get closed if you would post the second part of this question exactly like that there ("consuming SSRS but using a custom UI"), so you should provide more details/background -- if you should decide to ask there.

Answer (score 1):

There are few other minor generic project hostings (http://savannah.gnu.org/ and https://alioth.debian.org/ both clones of sourceforge code).

Most (IMHO, no citation) of the other projects are listed in language specific hosts (Perl: CPAN, Python: PyPI, R: CRAN, and many others).  But I don't know about sites on C#.  You could check if there are common links for C# in https://stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from GNU Savannah and Debian Alioth like the other answer states, the other possible places are www.apache.org and www.openhub.net, but your search should always start from Google. A search for "FOSS alternative for X" gives what you are looking for in most circumstances.